# Open html page in normal div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On click event i want to open the html page in div but the condition is i donot want use any type of server's it should run on loacl machine .This work fine in Mozila,but not in Chrome and IE.

I got this type of error in Chrome.
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/kaufman/Rev/NIC/Assets/common/introduction.htm. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

Please help

Comment: Any code samples that you've tried?

Comment: can you post your existing code?

Comment: I have just use jquery load function.

Comment: So what URL you putting in your JQuery `load`?

Answer (score 0):

if you use **Ajax** in Chrome  and IE for security reason Browser Didn't allow to Load local file.you Can Use **Iframe** for This.That mean make a **Ajax** by **Iframe** .make a hidden **Iframe** then set **src** .With **onload** event can understand **iframe** is load that time  you can get  **iframe** data with below  code

```
var iframeValue=document.getElementById('iframeID').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
alert(iframeValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain it better? 
Isn't an iframe `<iframe src="http://www.linkedpage.com"></iframe>` good for your needs?

iOS 5 added the following style that can be added to the parent div so that scrolling works.

```
jQuery("#div").css("-webkit-overflow-scrolling","touch")
```

Comment: Seems that mobile safari has some issues to scroll the iframe content. But i found this iOS 5 added the following style that can be added to the parent div so that scrolling works.

`code`-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch`code`

Comment: If you want to use it on iOS URLs like `file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/...` won't work.

Comment: @K.P I mean Make a **Ajax** from **Iframe**

Comment: aww you mean to access a local file with a local path. I guess that's going to be a problem then with an iframe, nevermind